# On HTML button press, send signal to Java on a whole other server

Tags: javascript, java, html

I currently have this setup:
1. Site somewhere on a server in for example Paris
2. Vps(Running a Bukkit server) on a whole other server.

And I am trying to make it when someone presses a button in html(on server 1), a Java funtion gets called(on server 2).
Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
This probably needs to go in php, becouse the browser should not be able to send requests...

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: It depends on more detailled information like which technologies / frameworks you use, and if the server have static / dynamic IPs, Domain names etc...

Comment: XmlHttpRequest in onClick handler. AKA "AJAX"

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ManuelM. !  
I can use MySQL, HTML, JavaScript and PhP on the site.  
And a Bukkit server running a plugin on the VPS.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I try to give an answer as detailed as possible with the given information.

In general this consists of two parts: Server A (Site) as the sending part, Server B (Bukkit) as the receiving part.

These two have to have a negotiation on how to communicate with each other. This could be eg. WebServices via REST or SOAP or even a Socket with an self designed protocol.

Both machines also need a connection with each other ie. an internet connection.

If we take webservices via REST as an example protocol, we would have to write in some code in an index.php file on server A:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Do action on remote server" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
function callRest($method, $url, $data = false) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method) {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
    callRest("POST", "http://my.remote-server.com/rest/do-something");
}

?>
```

This will call the remote server. If we have a REST Server running on our Server B (listening to /rest/do-something), it will get the call and we can call any Java function we want.